# Python **kwargs in parent and child constructor

Tags: python, inheritance

If I write an inheritance relationship as follows:

```
class Pet(object):
  def __init__(self, n):
    print n

class Dog(Pet):
  def __init__(self, **kwargs):
    Pet.__init__(self, 5)
```

Then the output is `5`.  If, however, I wanted to do:

```
class Pet(object):
  def __init__(self, **kwargs):
    if not "n" in kwargs:
      raise ValueError("Please specify the number I am to print")
    print kwargs["n"]

class Dog(Pet):
  def __init__(self, **kwargs):
    Pet.__init__(self, kwargs)
```

Then I get the error `TypeError: __init__() takes exactly one argument (two given)`

How can I pass the extra arguments up the inheritance chain in this way?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Simply pass the arguments down as keyword arguments:

```
class Pet(object):
  def __init__(self, **kwargs):
    if not "n" in kwargs:
      raise ValueError("Please specify the number I am to print")
    print kwargs["n"]

class Dog(Pet):
  def __init__(self, **kwargs):
    Pet.__init__(self, **kwargs)
```

However, you should use `super` rather than hardcoding the superclass.

Change your definition of `Dog` to (Python 2.X):

```
class Dog(Pet):
  def __init__(self, **kwargs):
    super(Dog, self).__init__(**kwargs)
```

And in Python 3.X it's nicer, just:

```
class Dog(Pet):
  def __init__(self, **kwargs):
    super().__init__(**kwargs)
```

Comment: if you use `super` then you should probably [use `super().__init__(**kwargs)` in Pet class (the base class), to support multiple inheritance](https://rhettinger.wordpress.com/2011/05/26/super-considered-super/).

Answer (score 2):

Figured it out:  Use `Pet.__init__(self, **kwargs)`

It's called "unpacking" and it transforms the dictionary `kwargs` into a list of argument=value pairs.

Then `**kwargs` in the parent constructor is able to handle them.  Just passing a dictionary would not work because `**kwargs` in the constructor is expecting a bunch of argument=value pairs but instead I was just passing it one value, the dictionary `kwargs` from the child.